# Issues with printing thai characters in jasper pdf report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing issues with printing jasper pdf report which contains thai or chinese characters.Report is getting generated but in place of thai character it displays ???? symbols.

Comment: no now i got the solution by placing Arial Unicode jar in my class path and by setting PDF-Encoding: Identity-H

Comment: Great, consider accepting the answer that is posted or to post your own so that question can be closed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ttf font for the thai/chinese char as extension.

The easiest way to do this is through [ireport-designer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer)

1. Download (or use one on your pc) your desired ttf font (for the specific language).
2. Install the font in ireport
3. Export the font extension (this creates a .jar)
4. Add the jar to your classpath.

This is a link for these step [iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-fonts) and this in [Jasper soft studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

I would try PDF-Encoding: **Idenity-H** (unicode with horizontal writing)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to follow this guide.
https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/displaying-east-asian-characters-report-pdf-output

if you used maven, You need  to add following dependencies to  your pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>arialunicode</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note: Arial Unicode library you need to install yours to your local maven repository.Please usee below  command**

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=arialunicode -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dfile=arialunicode-1.0.0.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Now you need to build your project and It should be ok.

Answer (score -1):

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jasper_report_template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="e35f5797-7de3-4d8d-ba9e-5320acff8a13">

```
        ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="414" y="3" width="121" height="15" uuid="f3706214-547a-4999-ace7-23d042c980bc"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[北京]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="3" width="136" height="15" uuid="42357a36-3ef3-4ae7-a4c6-0bbd6c8d501a"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="535" height="14" backcolor="#E5ECF9" uuid="5beb0b02-caaf-4d55-8d42-f6c52e238c58"/>
            <box>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#CCCCCC"/>
            </box>
            <text><![CDATA[

        ]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="414" y="0" width="121" height="15" uuid="e85c199d-04cc-4a05-b0ac-6817898320e5"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="136" height="15" uuid="339296ec-b8ba-49e7-bccc-b89c77eb3300"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```